# Show div even if empty

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I use Vuejs and have a component with div container which collapses if it's empty.

```
<template>
  <div>{{ content }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "myComponent",
  props: {
    content: String
  }
};
</script>
```

When consuming this component I could go for

```
<MyComponent content="text to show" />
```

but what if I want it to be empty? Then the div takes no space and collapses. I want to prevent it.

```html
<!-- This one takes no space -->
<div></div>
<div>This one takes space</div>
```

I thought about passing a unicode

https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+2800

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>&#10240;</div>
<div>This one takes space</div>
```

but the component does not convert it to a unicode character when receiving a string as a parameter.

Is there a solution using CSS instead of a unicode character?

I created a small example to show the current problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/o5l1kl290y

Comment: You could try adding a css rule for `min-height: 50px;`

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to show html properly in your component - just for future reference (rather than using a css hack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a non-breaking space (Unicode symbol `U+00A0`)  as the content of a pseudoelement only for `:empty` divs

```css
div:empty::before {
   content: "\A0";
}

div { border: 1px #ccc solid; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or you could set a specific `min-height` to `div:empty`

Answer (score 2):

You could add a space using an after pseudo element (then it will take the height of the font)

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

div:after {
  content:' ';
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>This one takes space</div>
```

Or if you want your vue component to show your html you can use

```
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

In place of your

```
<div>{{ content }}</div>
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jz47n8jv6)

Answer (score 1):

Not overly familiar with vue, but maybe?

`{{ content }}` could be `{{ content || "&nbsp;&nbsp;" }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-height to 50px (or less)

```
div {
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;

  min-height: 50px;
}
```